# what can i do to change exponent to normal number on shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I use ubuntu 20.04

I want to get disk usage by using

```
DISK_TOTAL=`df -P | grep -v ^Filesystem | awk '{sum += $2} END { print sum; }'`
DISK_USED=`df -P | grep -v ^Filesystem | awk '{sum += $3} END { print sum; }'`
DISK_PERCENT=$((100*$DISK_USED/$DISK_TOTAL))
```

But I received the error about one of result are exponent number.

I want to force to chage exponet number to normal number in shell script.

What code I use to solve this question?

Comment: Those commands work fine on my end. Please edit your post and paste these three things: 1) output of `echo $DISK_TOTAL` 2) output of `echo $DISK_USED` 3) exact error message

Comment: 3.9162e+10
40964444

is the result after i used echo

Comment: @YoanJeong : You did not specify, which shell you are using. In theory, your code could be bash, zsh or ksh. If you are running zsh, it should work. bash and ksh have, however, only integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Change the print in awk to

```
 { printf "%d\n", sum; }
```

However, if your number is too big to fit in an integer type, awk will still print it with exponent.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a personal note instead of just clicking solved.